# A Homology calculation Question

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $q: S^n\rightarrow S^n\vee S^n$ be the map we get quotienting the equator. What is $q_*$ on $n$-th Homology level? $q_*:\mathbf{Z}\rightarrow \mathbf{Z}\oplus\mathbf{Z}$ ?

Comment: What's your doubt?

Comment: @Randall Where does $q_*$ take the generator of $H_n(S^n)$, how can I visualize it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you follow up by collapsing say the second $S^n$ you get a map $S^n\to S^n$ which consists in collapsing the top hemisphere to a single point.

However the top hemisphere is a contractible sub-CW-complex, hence collapsing it is a homotopy equivalence.  Hence the induced map in homology is an isomorphism $\mathbb{Z\to Z}$ ($1$ or $-1$ depending on orientation but you can't really make a difference at that level).

Of course it's the same thing if you follow up by collapsing the first $S^n$.

Now use the fact that $H_q(X\vee Y)\to H_q(X)\oplus H_q(Y)$ obtained by summing the two "collapsing" maps is an isomorphism to conclude that your map is simply $\mathbb{Z\to Z\oplus Z}, x\mapsto (x,x)$ (with possible minus signs, but again, at this level you can't really make a difference)

Comment: If we fix the convention by regarding $S^n$ as two $n$-simplices $\Delta_1$ and $\Delta_2$ with their boundaries identified in the obvious way, and see $\Delta_1-\Delta_2$ as the generator of $H_n(S^n)$, can we figure out the signs then ?

Comment: And how do you glue $S^n\vee S^n$ ? both with a fixed pole ?

Comment: Yeah, the pole being the quotiented Equator

Comment: Well in this case you should try to work out the signs for yourself by looking at where $\Delta_1,\Delta_2$ are sent in terms of the smaller $\Delta_1,\Delta_2$'s modulo boundaries. It's probably easier to see it if you're taking a generator that's just one big simplex that covers $S^n$. If after trying that you still don't succeed I'll try to add a few words

Comment: The problem is $q$ is not exactly a simplicial map, so this technique can't be used directly. Anyway I will try my best. Thanks for the help @Max

Comment: Yes but this works for singular homology

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Max's answer I think this is how we can figure out the signs properly if we fix the convention as mentioned in the comments of Max's answer.

As pointed out by Max, to determine the map to each $\mathbf{Z}$ factor, we quotient out the other hemisphere and treat it as a map from $S^n$ to $S^n$. Now quotienting out the lower hemisphere will give us the map into the first factor of $\mathbf{Z}\oplus\mathbf{Z}$, which is $\mathbf{Z}\rightarrow\mathbf{Z}$; $x\mapsto x$. Now quotienting out the upper hemisphere will actually give us the map $x\mapsto -x$, because we can think of this map as first applying a rotation to $S^n$ interchanging the positions of the hemispheres, which takes $\Delta_1-\Delta_2$ to $\Delta_2-\Delta_1$. So this gives a $-1$ degree map, and then quotienting out the lower hemisphere gives identity from $\mathbf{Z}\rightarrow \mathbf{Z}$, so the composition is $x\mapsto-x$. So, $q_*$ should take $x$ to $(x,-x)$